# administrator permission are recommended for running visual studio sp1 on windows 7 rc

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7

I get this annoying message everytime I try to run visual studio 2005(even using "Run as Administrator" gives same message). I have VS 2005 Professional with all the latest service packs installed including vs2005 SP1 and vs 2005 update for Vista.

I am part of the administrators group on my machine. Still I have this problem.

Some read on the web suggests that Running program in Compatibility mode solves the problem.
Others also recommend turning off the message forever.

Well my question is how do I turn off this warning which seems to bother me even if I am part of administrators group. 
Does Visual Studio does not run in administrator mode even when I am an administrator or even I use "Run as adminsitrator".

Also it would be greate if someone out there can highlight what features of Visual Studio wont be available if Visual Studio is launched as a normal user (User is not an administrator/part of the administrator group) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the following article: 
http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2009/06/06/running-visual-studio-as-an-administrator-under-windows-vista/

Right-click a shortcut to Visual Studio, select the Compatibility tab, and check the ‘Run this program as an administrator’ checkbox at the bottom.

Works for me.

yes, this could remove this warnning message, but vs2005 will output a fatal error c1074 : IDB is not illeagl for PDB ... MS said that when build with XP mode compatibility, vs will generated this error.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, If you have UAC on, then by default, VSStudio will launch with std users right, even if the logged-in user is an admin.
You will need to run it as "Run As Administrator" to run it with full privileges. or run in built in Administrator's account.

If you run with std user's token, you will not be able to attach to applications that run with elevated permissions (ex. services) & processes running in someone else's account 9not very clear on this).

Also you will not be able to debug applications that need elevated privileges in the logged in account.

One solution is to make a short cut of VSStudio with run as administrator selected (via compatibility tab in properties of the shortcut). The other is turn off the warning & elevate only when required (recommended). Third is turn of UAC (worst option).

Comment: Nothing helps, neither turning UAC off.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem when using VS 2008 on XP Professional

Navigate to the devenv.exe file, right click and select properties.

Most likely the account under which you have logged in will be selected and the permissions will not include "Full Access". Click Full Access and then click OK.

This worked for me.

Comment: I missed a step, there. You need to click the Security Tab to see the list of permissions specific to the devenv.exe file

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem, even with permissions set to full access.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall VS 2005 on my Windows7 machine and now I got this message every time I start VS 2005

Selecting "Run this program as an administrator" wasn't sufficient for me: I still got the same message

After I also selected the option to run the program in compatability mode Windows XP SP3 the message did disappear though

Comment: In compatability mode it disappears, but Intellisense crashes VS after opening a sollution. After removing Intellisense, build fails also. Without compatibility mode all seems to be OK despite the initial warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. After I uninstalled the visual studio 2005 (restarted ) and reinstalled it the problem had gone away. Perhaps because vs 2005 update for Vista was this time installed before vs2005 sp1.

Comment: I was unable to install VS 2005 update for Vista first - it gives error "The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program." The same problem as here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901492/windows-7-visual-studio-2005-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I added full control permissions for users as recommended by Marcus P to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.
```

Then I noticed a checkbox in the lower left corner of the message to "show this message every time".  I unchecked the box.  I don't recall if the checkbox was there before I set the permissions, but I don't think it was.

Comment: With this checkbox you can hide the message, but the problem is still there.