# Windows 7 Visual Studio 2005 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7

I'm now working on RC Windows 7 and installed [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) Professional edition. But I need to work with Java programs, and so I needed to work with [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005). I installed Visual Studio 2005 SP1 (VS80sp1-KB926747), but I have the following problem:

> "The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch."

I previously had the same problem when I installed the Visual Studio SDK, February2007.

Comment: I assume that you mean J#, not Java.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on Superuser.com

Comment: Be careful with your setup language!
I tried to install the Team Suite SP1 VS80sp1-KB926601-X86-ENU.exe, but there is the same error message.
As my installation is in French, it seems that I must install the French version of the Team Suite SP1. On the SP1 DVD, I found the file VS80sp1-KB926607-X86-FRA.exe (E:\Multilanguage\VisualStudio2005SP1\Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite\French).
I also found the VS80sp1-KB932232-X86-FRA.exe (E:\French\VS2005SP1UpdateForVista).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBlake is right look at: https://superuser.com/questions/34190/visual-studio-2005-sp1-refuses-to-install-in-windows-7

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem when I was installing Visual Studio 2005 Professional on a Windows 7 machine. 
But here is what I did to fix the problem:

1. Install Visual Studio 2005 Professional
   During the install, a window popped up saying that VS2005 might not be compatible with Windows 7. Ignore this warning and continue.
2. Install Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005 Team Suite Service Pack 1 
   VS80sp1-KB926601-X86-ENU.exe
   Link: [Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005 Team Suite Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5553)
3. Install Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista
   VS80sp1-KB932232-X86-ENU.exe
   Link: [Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7524)

Note:
If you try and install #3 before #2, you will end up with a message that says :
"The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch."

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Hope it helps` --> yes indeed. much appreciated. posting the error message made it easier to find this answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to install SP1 (the patch) without having first installed Visual Studio 2005 (the application).  The SP1 install is only for patching an existing installation.